# How do I attach hinges to a media console?

Tags: woodworking, cabinets, hinges

I have an old media console with a door that used be attached via a sliding mechanism that I'd like to replace with hinges. I'd like for the door to open just like you'd open a cabinet.

I'm trying to think through which hinges to buy and where exactly to attach them to make sure everything is aligned.

[image: Detached media console]

I found some old Ikea cabinet hinges lying around, my guess is that I have a carve out a huge piece of the media console to install them, but perhaps I'm wrong. I don't mind at all buying new hinges for this project, but found these so figured I'd ask.

[image]

Many thanks for the tips / advice!

Comment: With a slim frame like that, you're better off with a piano hinge than cabinet hinges, which you don't seem to need anyway as there's not another cabinet door right next to it.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. A piano hinge makes a lot of sense, thanks for the suggestion. If I use a piano hinge, will I be able to mount it so it looks centered in the enclosure?

Comment: It looks like it, especially if you find a good match for the width of the hinge and the margin between the hinge's edge and holes. If not, you can go with the other suggestion, but you might have to wood glue a shim/standoff/block or two to build-up the wall and door thickness so that the wood's thick enough to take recessed hinges and screws. My concern is that they are too thin, but I do like hidden hinges, so it might be worth that effort.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the frame is thick enough to hold the hinges, the tool of choice is usually a [Forstner bit](https://amzn.to/35kflVD):

[image]

You don't need a whole set - if you know exactly what you need, you can just get one size.

There are also plenty of hinges that simply use screws and don't require a big hole. Depending on the specifics, that may be better.

Comment: There are cabinet hinge jig sets that come with the correct forstner bit and the jig to get the correct position to drill. I use the Kreg but there are several.  https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=cabinet+hinge+jig&ia=web

Comment: Thank you both. Any tips on how to see if the panel is thick enough? I looked into it and it’s not absolutely clear.

Comment: @AndrewP Hold hinge up to face frame of cabinet door and see if it is deeper then the thickness of the face frame.